# How to Re-Merge after Rollback of Previous Merge

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, merge, rollback, changeset

We're using Visual Studio 2015.

I have three branches, 'DEV' where new code is made, 'MAIN', where tested good code goes as the primary repository, and 'PRE' where edits are made to previously released code. (PRE changes can be merged into DEV easily since we should never be working on the same file in two places)

That said, I merged good code from PRE to MAIN with no issues. I checked in those changes. When I merged that code from MAIN to DEV, there was conflict in the .sln file, but this is nothing new. Some new projects exist in DEV that don't yet exist in MAIN or PRE, so there's always some shuffling. I used the merge tool and attempted to resolve the conflict.

I completed the merge, and checked in the changeset. Only after check in do I realize there was a problem in the merge of the .sln file and I cannot build the solution because the paths for the files got crossed/corrupted somehow.

The error I receive is 'Metadata file \path\folders\buildlocation\solution.dll could not be found'. This error is repeated for every project. **EDIT: I solved the problem with the build. It was not a .sln problem, but an error in the shared library.**

===========================

**That said, I believe the question below is still valid, if someone should ever need it.**

So here's the question: I know I can do a rollback on DEV to get back to the previous state, but this creates 'new' changes which need to be checked in, which will overwrite the previous change. However, once that's done, I will still need to attempt to re-merge the good changes from MAIN back into DEV. Since that changeset is already merged, it is no longer available as a merge candidate.

How can I A) Rollback checked in changes from a merge in DEV and then B) Re-merge those changes into DEV and attempt to do it correctly?